# How get Region ID or Region Name in Oracle Apex 5

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

I want to implement Authorization Scheme using my own created tables,for this purpose I want to get Current Region Name ,how to get it?

Comment: You mean region title?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure how you plan to tackle this, but component level attributes might be your bag http://www.explorer-development.uk.com/component-level-authorization-apex-5-0/

Answer (score 2):

First, you'll need to assign a static id to your region.. then you can query the apex_application_page_regions table.

```
SELECT region_name
FROM   apex_application_page_regions
WHERE  static_id      = 'SOME_STATIC_ID'
AND    page_id        = :APP_PAGE_ID
AND    application_id = :APP_ID;
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't actually need to assign a static ID for this purpose. There is a column `REGION_ID` in the `apex_application_page_regions` table. So filter out that column based on REGION_NAME.

```
select region_id from apex_application_page_regions
where region_name = 'your_region_name';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily turn this into a function for future use:

```
function get_region_id (p_app_id number, p_app_page_id number, p_ir_static_id varchar2) return number is  

    l_region_id number;
begin

    select region_id into l_region_id
    from apex_application_page_regions
    where application_id   = p_app_id   
        and page_id            = p_app_page_id
        and upper(static_id)   = upper(p_ir_static_id)  
        and upper(template)    = upper('Interactive Report');

    return l_region_id; 

end get_region_id;
```